# How the relationship of StepScalingPolicy and StepScalingAction to set for the alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I am planning to increase the instance number by alarm.

Currenty My source code is like this below.

```
const stepScalingPolicy = new autoscaling.StepScalingPolicy(this, 'MyStepScalingPolicy', {
  autoScalingGroup: props!.aiAutoScalingGroup,
  metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
    namespace: `tt-${targetEnv}-gpu`,// myAlarm
    metricName: 'GPU Usage'
  }),
  scalingSteps: [{
    upper:10,lower:0,change: 1,
  }, { lower: 888, upper: 999, change: 0 }],
});


const stepScalingAction = new autoscaling.StepScalingAction(this, "ScaleOutAction",{
  autoScalingGroup:props!.myAutoScalingGroup,
  adjustmentType:autoscaling.AdjustmentType.CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY
  }
);
const autoScalingAction = new actions.AutoScalingAction(stepScalingAction);
myAlarm.addAlarmAction(autoScalingAction);
```

However it shows error ,

```
You must specify an AdjustmentType for policy type: StepScaling (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 64598d63-c4c8-42bd-b9df-58995ba50679)"
```

(RequestToken: 67766f9a-7a97-c892-98d0-3a9f25d9c891, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

However I put the `adjustmentType` in `StepScalingAction` already.

And I am confuswd about relationship of `StepScalingAction`,`StepScalingPolicy` and alarm.

I guss alarm has to have the `StepScalingAction` as action.

However where the `StepScalingPolicy` belonging to ????

Any help appreciated.